# When does $nx^4+4x+3=0$ have real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> Find all positive integers $n$ such that the equation $nx^4+4x+3=0$ has real roots.

I think the answer must also include the cases with $2$ real roots. But my main question is, how do I start? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
nx^4+4x+3 & = (n-1)x^4 + x^4+4x+3 = (n-1)x^4 + (x+1)^2((x-1)^2+2)\\
& = (n-1)x^4 + (x^2-1)^2 + 2(x+1)^2
\end{align}
Hence, for $n \geq 2$, the function is a sum of squares and is always positive, since all three of them cannot be simultaneously zero and therefore has no real roots.

For $n=1$, we see that $x=-1$ is the only possible real root.

Comment: Nice! Perhaps it could be worth it to add an intermediate step between the second and third expressions, since that factoring is not immediate.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is positive for large $x$ so the question is equivalent to asking whether the minimum is negative. Find this minimum (it is unique) by solving for zero derivative.

The condition that the minimum be negative is a polynomial inequality in $n$ which is not difficult to solve.

Comment: Neat. But given the 'pre-calculus' tag, I don't think he knows (or is allowed to use) derivatives, which makes this strategy less helpful...